# Router Password changed automatically and Teredo port opened upon reboot?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, passwords, port-forwarding, teredo

How do I prevent this from keep happening I had to factory reset router a few times due to random ports being opened?

I went to connect my phone to the WiFi and I kept receiving password was incorrect error though I had other devices with the same password still connected to router. Immediately I power cycle the router and it first is detected as an open network then shows as secured and I am able to connect. I log into the router to see the password and it is still the same though I have a Teredo port open allowing remote connections as seen in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got weird things happening, some of which look very insecure, and some of which look like functionality issues?

Buy a new router/firewall/access point.  If you want to get a little advanced, try something in the [Ubiquiti Edgemax](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#edgemax) line for the firewall; they start off very inexpensive, and have regular firmware updates.

You can try something in the [Ubiquiti Unifi](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#unifi) line for wifi access points (warning: you need a controller service to configure it at least the first time, and to patch it), or put whatever consumer router you want inside the real router/firewall.